# How do I copy (by value) a python object make from a class?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am stuck with copying values in instances of a python class. What I want to do it create an original class object (with some default values) and then create multiple copies that contain different values, *without affecting the original object*.
The code below is a simple example and demonstrates the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import copy

class tester:
    test_val    =   0.0

def copy_orig(obj_in):
    obj_out =   copy.deepcopy(obj_in)
    return obj_out

def make_orig():
    my_obj  =   tester
    my_obj.test_val = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.])
    return my_obj

orig_obj    =   make_orig()
new_obj =   copy_orig(orig_obj)

print 'Original array (pre-mod):    ',orig_obj.test_val
new_obj.test_val[3]=10.
print 'Original array (post-mod):   ',orig_obj.test_val
print 'New array (post-mod):        ',new_obj.test_val
```

This prints:

> Original array (pre-mod): [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.]
>
> Original array (post-mod):    [  1.   2.   3.  10.   5.]
>
> New array (post-mod):     [  1. 2.   3.  10.   5.]

But what I want is for the original array to be the same both pre- and post- but the new array to contain the number 10 at index 3.

As well as copy.deepcopy I have also tried adding the lines:

```
obj_out.test_val    =   copy.deepcopy(obj_in.test_val)
```

and

```
obj_out.test_val[:] =   obj_in.test_val
```

Neither of these work. I presumed this would be quite simple, so it'd be great if someone could point me in the right direction.
Thanks.

-edit- This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035637/how-do-i-copy-by-value-a-python-object-make-from-a-class) as I have tried the solutions given there without success.

Comment: @martijn-pieters: This is not a duplicate as the solution posted in the other question does not work for me. I even mentioned that solution in my question (which I've now edited to make it more clear).

Comment: If you are trying to deepcopy your class instance *containing* `numpy.array` objects, you'll have to create a `__copy__` or `__deepcopy__` method. See the bottom of the [`copy` module documenation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html), and use the techniques in the other answers to create a copy of the numpy list.

Comment: Nowhere in your question do you mention using those techniques. What did you try, how did they fail?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I do - see the last code section of my question. I have now solved this problem but am unable to answer my own question as you still have it erroneously marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Then please edit your question into shape where it is clear what you tried from the duplicate and how it doesn't apply to your specific problem. As it stands it is not clear what you are asking then if not about copying a numpy array.